# checkboxGroupInput value for dplyr filtering

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

I have a question about the usage of the checkboxGroupInput. We would like to make a filter that can filter the months of de dates from the dataframe. In the filter function of dplyr we have to use c(1,2,3,4) <- as example. Now we want to generate this with a checkboxGroupInput so we can show selected months in a ggplot.

It works with the following code:

```
filter(Location  == input$locatie & month(Month_StartConnection) %in% c(1,2,3,4))
```

c(1,2,4,5) must be dynamic with the checkboxGroupInput input.

Thanks

```
## app.R ##
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Test", tabName = "KPI", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "KPI",
              fluidRow(
                checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "seizoen", label = "Seizoen", choices = list("Alle Maanden", 1,2,"mrt","apr", "mei", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "okt", "nov", "dec"), value = TRUE),
                selectInput(inputId = "locatie",
                                   label = h3("Locatie"),
                                   choices = c("Speerpunt","Museum","Strandweg", "Zwarte pad", "Prins Clauslaan", "Prinsessegracht", "Fluwelen Burgwal", "Kranestraat", "Heulstraat", "Kneuterdijk", "Hoge Nieuwstraat", "Kijkduin", "De Uithof", "Zwembad het Hofbad", "Kyocera stadion", "Stadhuis"),
                                   selected = 1
                ),
                plotOutput("ggplot", height = 600, width= 600)
              )
      ),

      # Second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
              h2("Widgets tab 1")
      )
    )
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$ggplot <- renderPlot({

    print(
      Merge_Charge_Point %>%
        select(Charge_Point_ID, Location, kWh, Month_StartConnection) %>%
        filter(Location  == input$locatie & month(Month_StartConnection) %in% c(input$seizoen)) %>%
        group_by(Month_StartConnection) %>%
        summarise(aantal_sessies = n()) %>%
        filter(Month_StartConnection < as.Date(format(as.Date(strptime(Sys.Date(),"%Y-%m-%d",tz="")) ,format = "%y-%m-1")))%>%
        ggplot(aes(Month_StartConnection, aantal_sessies, group = 1))+
        geom_line()+scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%y-%m")) +
        geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
    ) 
  })
} 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: because it's a `checboxGroupInput` you need to use `%in%`, instead of `==` : e.g., `filter(Location %in% input$locatie)`. This is because `checkboxGroupInput` gives you a `vector` of values

Comment: Thanks for your input, but we are looking for an answer for this code:
month(Month_StartConnection) %in% c(input$seizoen))

Comment: just a hunch, but try changing the `list( ... )` to `c( ... )` - for example
`choices = c("Alle Maanden", 1,2,"mrt", ...)`

Comment: Thanks SymbolixAU, But it doesn't work. :(

Comment: How many elements does `input$locatie` have? If you query a mySql server, it won't work if `input$locatie` has only 1 or 0 elements

Answer (score 0):

First of all You should post some sample data, without it it is actually not possible to check Your code, if it is actually working....

On base of what You showed, i think the problem is with:

`...%in% c(input$seizoen))...`

You should only use:

```
...%in% input$seizoen)...
```

no `c(...)`!!

**[SAMPLE CODE]**
Have a look at it, I have not seen Your data, thats why i had to create some sample data to show You that my answer is correct (if it is only about checkboxGroupInput value for dplyr filtering)

```
## app.R ##
library(shinydashboard)

x <- c("Alle Maanden", 1,2,"mrt","apr", "mei", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "okt", "nov", "dec")
y <- c(1:13)

data <- data.frame(x,y)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Test", tabName = "KPI", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "KPI",
              fluidRow(
                checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "seizoen", label = "Seizoen", choices = list("Alle Maanden", 1,2,"mrt","apr", "mei", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "okt", "nov", "dec")),
                selectInput(inputId = "locatie",
                            label = h3("Locatie"),
                            choices = c("Speerpunt","Museum","Strandweg", "Zwarte pad", "Prins Clauslaan", "Prinsessegracht", "Fluwelen Burgwal", "Kranestraat", "Heulstraat", "Kneuterdijk", "Hoge Nieuwstraat", "Kijkduin", "De Uithof", "Zwembad het Hofbad", "Kyocera stadion", "Stadhuis"),
                            selected = 1
                ),
                plotOutput("ggplot", height = 600, width= 600)
              )
      ),

      # Second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
              h2("Widgets tab 1")
      )
    )
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$ggplot <- renderPlot({
    print(input$seizoen)
    data <- data %>%
        filter(x %in% input$seizoen) 
    print(data)

    g <- ggplot(data,aes(x=x,y=y))+ geom_point()
    g

  })
} 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is not possible to show the output, but I can show a screenshot. I have tried your code but is doesn't work. 
[Image of dashboad](http://i64.tinypic.com/5uolxs.png)
I got the following error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x, y, group

Comment: have a look at the edit!! Error: it seems that smthg is wrong with your code starting from `Merge_Charge_Point %>%
        select(Charge_Point_ID, Location, kWh, Month_StartConnection) %>%` but without the data its hard to say for me